# sudzc how to use the returned object from ws call

Tags: objective-c, sudzc

The sudzc generated stub is:

`(void)HandleSearchResult: (id) value { ...`

The document indicates that "value" can be cast into `(SDZSearchItemsByUpcResponse *)`. However that was not true.

In XCode, the type of "value" appears to be `__NSCFDictionary`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__NSCFDictionary` is a concrete subclass of either `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`. Handle like so:

```
-(void)handleSearchResult:(id)value {
    NSDictionary* dict = value;
    NSLog(@"value is: %@", dict);
    // Do what you want with your dictionary
}
```

I would skip SudzC and use `CWXMLTranslator` from https://github.com/jayway/CWFoundation. It allows you to ignore most of the cruft in SOAP XML responses, and translates directly to proper domain objects, not dictionaries and other placeholders.

Comment: dear PeyloW, Can you please provide more info about why to skip SudzC and use CWXMLTranslator ? I tried to contact you but didnt find any email or ID . thanks in advance.

Comment: @MiladRk I say the best explanation as to why you should use CWXMLTranslator is in this repo https://github.com/PeyloW/CWFoundation, it has a sample RSS feed parser in 9 lines of SDL. If there is an easier way to handle XML then I would like to know about it.